# Exploiting a buffer overflow in a jmp_buf struct

Tags: c, linux, buffer-overflow, setjmp

I need help to exploit a buffer overflow on a jmp_buf structure.

I have the following values on the stack (seen by gdb):

```
0xbffffc40:     0xb7fd8ff4      0x080485a0      0x080483f0      0xbffffcf8
0xbffffc50:     0xebf06081      0x1d0a15ee
```

The second one is the next IP (after the setjmp) but if i modify it i do not change the behavior of my program.

I noticed that I can change the flow (and obtain a Segmentation) only if i modify the value of the last one.

But, I can not understand the meaning of the last word and how to change it to obtain the desired behavior.

Comment: Hopefully this needs a 'homework' tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am trying to do the same at the moment - i do not know what os you are using, but i found the following docu 
(@ http://freebsd.active-venture.com/FreeBSD-srctree/newsrc/dev/vinum/vinummemory.c.html) for freebsd which simpy discribes the jmpbuf struct:

```
struct JmpBuf {
    int jb_ebx; //in your case --> 0xb7fd8ff4      
    int jb_esp; //in your case --> 0x080485a0
    int jb_ebp; //in your case --> 0x080483f0      
    int jb_esi; //in your case --> 0xbffffcf8
    int jb_edi; //in your case --> 0xebf06081      
    int jb_eip; //in your case --> 0x1d0a15ee
    };
```

Therefore 0x080485a0 would be the stored ESP and not EIP which would explain the segfault in your case...

Comment: Heilà, thanks for the answer..!
I found the same jmp_buf description..the problem is that i'm sure that the address 0x080485a0 is the next instruction at the moment of the setjmp call and 0x1d0a15ee (which should be the EIP) points to "god knows where", or maybe it's an offset, or something else..
I really can't understand how it works, i also tried to disassemble the longjmp function..but i can't understand it..

However, thank you very much for the answer!

Comment: Hi! I created on long jump exploit yesterday on an ubuntu 10.4LTS 32Bit system. Therefore I read a lot articles about that and I found out that the implementation differs a lot between different OSes. What OS are you using? Maybe I can help you when you using ubuntu too?